# Show that $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square if and only if $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})\ m=np^s$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I want to show the following lemma:

> Assume that the characteristic of the field $F$ is $p$ and $p>2$. 
>   Then $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square in $F[t, t^{-1}]$ ($F[t,t^{-1}]$: the polynomials in $t$ and $t^{-1}$ with coefficients in $F$) if and only if $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z})\ m=np^s$.

I have done the following:

$\Leftarrow $ :

$$\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1} \overset{ m=np^s }{ = } \frac{t^{np^s}-1}{t^n-1}=\frac{(t^n)^{p^s}-1}{t^n-1}=\frac{(t^n-1)((t^n)^{p^s-1}+\dots +1)}{t^n-1}=(t^n)^{p^s-1}+\dots +1$$

Is this correct so far?

How can we continue to conclude that $(t^m-1)/(t^n-1)$ is a square ?

$\Rightarrow $ :

$$\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}=a^2 \Rightarrow t^m-1=a^2(t^n-1)$$

How can we continue?

Comment: I am wondering why you are assuming implicitly that $$\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1} \in F[t,t^{-1}]$$ In general this is not true. Clearly this holds in the hypothesis that $n$ divides $m$ (baceuase it belongs to $F[t]$). But is this the case?

Comment: We have to show that $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ is a square iff $(\exists s \in \mathbb{Z}) m=np^s$, which means that $n$ divides $m$, or not? @Crostul

Comment: It seems to me that this lemma makes no sense. If $n$ divides $m$, then the fraction $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ belongs to $F[t]$ which is integrally closed because it is a PID. This means that (in the hypothesis that $n$ divides $m$) $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ is a square in $F[t,t^{-1}]$ if and only if it is a square in $F[t]$. Now, you are not assuming that $n$ divides $m$, however it seems that you are assuming that $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ belongs to $F[t, t^{-1}]$, but in general this is false. So: are you making some special assumptions on $n,m$?

Comment: The lemma is exactly as I wrote it above... There is no ther assumptions on $n, m$... @Crostul

Answer (score 3):

In this proof, $m$ and $n$ are assume to be positive integers (not stated in the question by the OP). Also, $F$ is taken to be a ***field*** of a prime characteristic $p>2$. (The OP never stated what $F$ is clearly.)  Furthermore, I shall show that $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$ if and only if $m=n\cdot p^s$ for some ***nonnegative integer*** $s$.  (The OP says that $s \in \mathbb{Z}$, but that is not true.)

If $\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}\in F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$, then there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ such that $t^k\left(\frac{t^{m}-1}{t^{n}-1}\right)\in F[t]$.  Now, this means $t^{n}-1$ divides $t^k\left(t^{m}-1\right)$ in $F[t]$.  As $\gcd\left(t^{n}-1,t^k\right)=1$ (in $F[t]$), we must have that $t^{n}-1$ divides $t^{m}-1$ in $F[t]$.  It is then an easy task to show that $m=nr$ for some $r\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, we assume that $\frac{t^{nr}-1}{t^n-1}$, which is in $F[t]$, is a square in $F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$.  Then, $\frac{t^{nr}-1}{t^n-1}=\big(g(t)\big)^2$ for some $g(t)\in F\left[t,t^{-1}\right]$.  Since $\big(g(t)\big)^2\in F[t]$, it follows that $g(t)\in F[t]$.  Suppose that $n=p^l x$ and $s=p^s y$ for some $l,s\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p\nmid x$ and $p\nmid y$.  We have
$$\big(g(t)\big)^2=\frac{t^{nr}-1}{t^n-1}=\left(\frac{t^{xr}-1}{t^x-1}\right)^{p^l}\,.$$  As $p^l$ is odd, $\frac{t^{xr}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$.  Hence, for some $h(t)\in F[t]$, we have
$$\frac{t^{xr}-1}{t^x-1}=\big(h(t)\big)^2\,.$$
Now, observe that $t^{xr}-1=\left(t^{xy}-1\right)^{p^s}$, so that
$$\big(h(t)\big)^2=\left(t^{xy}-1\right)^{p^s-1}\,\left(\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}\right)\,.$$
Since $p^s-1$ is even, we deduce that $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$.

If $y>1$, $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is nonconstant.  Therefore, in the algebraic closure $\bar{F}$ of $F$, $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$, whence $t^{xy}-1$, has a multiple root in $\bar{F}$.  This means $xy\,t^{xy-1}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(t^{xy}-1\right)$ shares a common root with $t^{xy}-1$ in $\bar{F}$.   Because $\gcd\left(t^{xy}-1,t^{xy-1}\right)=1$, we deduce that $xy=0$ in $F$, but this violates the assumption that $p$ divides neither $x$ nor $y$.  Hence, $y>1$ is false.  That is $y=1$.  Now, this means $r=p^s$, or $m=np^s$.

Conversely, if $m= n\cdot p^s$, then
$$\frac{t^m-1}{t^n-1}=\frac{\left(t^{n} -1\right)^{p^s}}{t^n-1}=\left(t^n-1\right)^{p^s-1}$$
is a square, as $2\mid p^s-1$.  The claim is now proven.

Comment: At the first direction I have the following questions: $$$$ - Why do we suppose at the beginning of the proof that $n=p^lx$ and $r=p^sy$ for some $l, s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p \not\mid x$ and $p \not\mid y$ ?

Comment: - At the point where you say: "Now, observe that $t^{xr}-1=(t^{xy}-1)^{p^s}$, so that $(h(t))^2=(t^{xy}-1)^{p^s-1}\left (\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}\right )$. Since $p^s-1$ is even, we deduce that $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$" When $p^s-1$ is even it is a multiple of $2$, so the expression $(t^{xy}-1)^{p^s-1}\left (\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}\right )$ is a multiple of $2$. So, why do we deduce that $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$? $$$$- Could you explain to me the following part? "Because $\text{gcd}(t^{xy}-1, t^{xy-1})=1$, we deduce that $xy=0$ in $F$"

Comment: For the first question, I can suppose that because every positive integer $n$ has a form $p^lx$ with $p\nmid x$.  The same with $r$.

Comment: If $a(t),b(t),c(t)\in F[t]$ are such that $c(t)=\big(a(t)/b(t)\big)^2$, then $b(t)\mid a(t)$ and $c(t)=\big(d(t)\big)^2$ for some $d(t)\in F[t]$.  That is, $d(t)=a(t)/b(t)$.

Comment: The only root of $t^{xy-1}$ is $0$, while no zeros of $t^{xy}-1$ is $0$, whence the gcd is $1$.  This means: if $xy\,t^{xy-1}$ and $t^{xy}-1$ has a common root, that common root $x=u$ is a root of $t^{xy}-1$.  That is, $xy\,u^{xy-1}=0$ and $u^{xy}-1=0$.  Hence, $xy=xy\cdot 1=xy\cdot u^{xy}=\big(xy\cdot u^{xy-1}\big)u=0\cdot u=0$.

Comment: I still haven't understood my second question... $$$$ When we have a nonconstant expression, like $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$, do we conclude that in the algebraic closure it will have a multiple root? It stands that if a polynomail has a multiple root, the derivative will share this root, right? I haven't understood at your last comment at which point we use the fact that the $\text{gcd}$ of $t^{xy-1}$ and $t^{xy}-1$ is $1$. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: In my explanation, I didn't use the fact that the gcd is $1$.  I just explained why the gcd is $1$ (although I mindlessly wrote "this means: ...", which I just found out that it is misleading).  However, there is an alternative route to use the fact that the gcd is $1$, but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean that a polynomial having a multiple root in the algebraic closure.  The polynomial $t$ clearly doesn't.  However, a square of a nonconstant polynomial does.

Comment: I see... You say that "If $y>1$, $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is nonconstant.  Therefore, in the algebraic closure $\bar{F}$ of $F$, $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$, whence $t^{xy}-1$, has a multiple root in $\bar{F}$.". We know that $t^{xy}-1$ has a multiple root in the algebraic closure because the power of $t$ is greater than $1$, right?

Comment: No, it's because $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a nonconstant square.

Comment: I see... Could you explain to me further the part "Now, observe that $t^{xr}-1=\left(t^{xy}-1\right)^{p^s}$, so that
$$\left (h(t)\right )^2=\left(t^{xy}-1\right)^{p^s-1}\ \left(\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}\right)\ .$$
Since $p^s-1$ is even, we deduce that $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$." ? I still haven't understood how we deduce that $\frac{t^{xy}-1}{t^x-1}$ is a square in $F[t]$ from the fact that $p^s-1$ is even.

Comment: I already did: see reply above that looks like
If a(t),b(t),c(t)∈F[t] are such that c(t)=(a(t)/b(t))^2, then b(t)∣a(t) and c(t)=(d(t))^2 for some d(t)∈F[t]. That is, d(t)=a(t)/b(t).

Comment: Does $a(t)$ represent the expression $t^{xy}-1$, $b(t)$ the expression $t^x-1$ and $c(t)$ the expression $\frac{(h(t))^2}{(t^{xy}-1)^{p^s-1}}$ ?